# How to view the modules which and loaded and enabled in Apache?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

How to view the modules which and loaded and enabled in Apache in Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `httpd -h`:

```
  -t -D DUMP_MODULES : show all loaded modules
```

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate command is:

httpd -M